# What is the breakdown of Happy Home Academy points?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

For the previous Animal Crossing games, people have published breakdowns of what assigns point values in Happy Home/Room Academy evaluations (e.g. [here](http://animalcrossing.wikia.com/wiki/Happy_Room_Academy#Animal_Crossing_.28GCN.29)).

Is this information available for New Leaf?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so, but it would be safe to assume that they are very similar to the GCN and WW numbers. In general these sorts of things change very little from AC game to game, the changes seem only to be balancing tweaks.